# What pressure can be considered ideal behavior of water vapor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

Water vapor is in the range of ideal behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out under which conditions water vapor can be approximated as an ideal gas by making us of the **principle of corresponding states**, and determining the compressibility factor z (i.e., PV=znRT) using this principal.  According to this principle, the compressibility factor is a universal function of the reduced pressure (pressure divided by critical pressure) and reduced temperature (temperature divided by critical temperature).  The relationship between z and reducted temperature and pressure can be found in most thermo books.  If the compressibility factor z is close to 1.0 according to the universal graph, the behavior is approximately ideal gas.  As a rule of thumb, if the vapor pressure is less than about 10 bars, the ideal gas law will give a pretty good approximation.

Comment: In relation to the rule of thumb that said [if the vapor pressure is less than about 10 bars, the ideal gas law will give a pretty good approximation] , is it possible to refer to the source cited that it?

Comment: Google yourself a copy of the thermodynamic Steam Tables for water, and see the section on superheated steam.  This gives actual values of specific volume as a function of temperature and pressure.  Compare the data with the ideal gas law.

Comment: If you do not have access to professional steam tables, you may want to consider using the steam tables that are included in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/SteamTables.html).

Comment: Professional quality steam tables are provided for free over the internet in the form of pdf's.